# R: aggregate daily to weekly data by group

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I have a dataset with daily data per country. I would now like to aggregate it to weekly data by taking the weekly mean. I found several solutions for doing this. However, I have not found sources for doing this by group (or by country in my case).

Here is what my data loks like:

```
  Country       Date StringencyIndex
1   Aruba 2020-01-01               0
2   Aruba 2020-01-02               0
3   Aruba 2020-01-03               0
4   Aruba 2020-01-04               0
5   Aruba 2020-01-05               0
6   Aruba 2020-01-06               0
```

The goal is to have weekly values for StringencyIndex **by country**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Country, week = lubridate::week(Date)) %>%
  summarise(StringencyIndex = mean(StringencyIndex))
```

Base R `aggregate` -

```
aggregate(StringencyIndex~Country + week, transform(df, week = format(Date, '%V')), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(StringencyIndex = mean(StringencyIndex, na.rm = TRUE)),
          .(Country, week = week(Date))]
```